# How to encode factor predictors in prediction models

Tags: r, encoding, prediction, factors

The response variable as well as all predictor variables in my dataset are factors. I want to build a model for predicting the response variable. As I understand I have to first encode my predictor variables. I need advise on how to do the same in R.

I tried building knn & Random Forest models, but this is not working as the execution is never getting completed.

"rs" is the response variable and all others are predictor variables. "bt" depends on "td" but others are completely independent.

Below is the structure of my dataframe.

```
    > str(df)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   17520 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ rs  : Factor w/ 8 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 1 5 1 3 3 3 2 1 5 8 ...
 $ bno : Factor w/ 135 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ bttm: Factor w/ 13 levels "tm 1","tm 10",..: 5 12 10 7 10 12 1 13 7 6 ...
 $ bwtm: Factor w/ 13 levels "tm 1","tm 10",..: 11 11 7 9 9 8 12 11 4 9 ...
 $ bts : Factor w/ 348 levels "pl 100","pl 101",..: 207 295 114 246 328 318 312 14 147 118 ...
 $ tw  : Factor w/ 13 levels "tm 1","tm 10",..: 7 9 5 12 5 1 11 8 9 7 ...
 $ td  : Factor w/ 2 levels "b","f": 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ bwl : Factor w/ 282 levels "pl 10","pl 106",..: 60 160 123 71 139 9 109 229 6 148 ...
 $ bt  : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ ven : Factor w/ 41 levels "v 1","v 10","v 11",..: 6 21 35 26 34 13 23 10 17 25 ...
>
```

I would like to know the approach I shall take and code to encode the predictor variables.

Comment: Have you tried to coerce the predictors to class `"factor"` with `as.factor`? R's modeling functions generally do this automatically but if you're having problems you can try doing it by hand.

Comment: `df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], as.factor)`.

Comment: I have re-posted the correct structure of the dataframe. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using tree-based methods, you do not need to encode your variables.

Using knn on such kind of data is not a good idea because all you have is categorical variables. If we encode them, your matrix will be extremely sparse and using an algorithm which calculates distances between your points by their coordinates will be extremely time consuming and misleading.

You may try to decrease number of your categories by updating your factor levels. For instance, your `bts` vector has 348 distinct categories. Are there any categories which have observations less than ,for example, 10? **Among 348, there may be a lot of groups that have limited number of observations.** You can group these categories **into a single one**. If you apply it to other vectors such as `bwl` and `bno` your data frame dimension will significantly decrease in case you perform encoding. Even if you do not do encoding, it will help for tree-based algorithm to take less time.

Comment: please do not forget to upvote or accept the answer if it works for you. best